# Why do the two template functions differ in output?

Tags: c++, templates, auto, type-deduction

Why do the two template functions `FuncOne` and `FuncTwo` differ in output?

```
template <class T>
T * FuncOne(T & v)
{
    auto a = reinterpret_cast<const volatile char &>(v);
    auto b = & const_cast<char&>(a);
    auto c = reinterpret_cast<T *>(b);
    return c;    
}

template <class T>
T * FuncTwo(T & v)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<T *>(& const_cast<char&> (reinterpret_cast<const volatile char &>(v)));
}
```

Code to test the two functions:

```
int main()
{       
  nonaddressable na;
  nonaddressable * naptr = FuncOne(na); 
  cout << "FuncOne: naptr = " << naptr << endl;
  naptr = FuncTwo(na); 
  cout << "FuncTwo: naptr = " << naptr << endl;

  nonaddressable * nbptr = new nonaddressable;
  cout << "Address of nbptr = " << nbptr << endl;  
  cout << "FuncOne: nbptr = " << FuncOne(*nbptr) << endl; 
  cout << "FuncTwo: nbptr = " << FuncTwo(*nbptr) << endl;
}
```

Sample Output:

```
FuncOne: naptr = 0x61fddf   
FuncTwo: naptr = 0x61fe2f   

Address of nbptr = 0x7216e0   
FuncOne: nbptr = 0x61fddf   
FuncTwo: nbptr = 0x7216e0
```

As we can see from comparing the values of `nbptr`, `FuncTwo` gives the expected and correct output. But why does not `FuncOne` give the same output as it is just another way of writing `FuncTwo`?

Compiler Used: g++ 7.1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FuncOne` is not another way of writing `FuncTwo`. It would be if you replaced the line

```
 auto a = reinterpret_cast<const volatile char &>(v);
```

by

```
 auto& a = reinterpret_cast<const volatile char &>(v);
```

Otherwise the reference in `const volatile char&` will be dropped during [type-deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Other_contexts) for `a`.